# Custom Object not Visible in SF

Tags: custom-object, system-admin

Salesforce Admin newbie here.

I've picked up support of an org that I was not involved in building.  There is a formula field in 3 or 4 small custom objects I need to investigate and possibly change.

I know these objects exist as they are referenced in Apex.  The thing I don't understand is I can export/upsert via dataloader but I've been unable to make them visible in Salesforce to review the formula fields even with my System Administrator profile in Lightning or Classic.

Where do I go to make these objects visible?

Thanks!

Comment: The tab may be hidden for the Profile, can you check on profile and make sure it is 'Default On'? (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000330223&type=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that tabs are not created for those objects.
Go to Setup -> Tabs, and try to find them under custom tabs.
If they do not exist just create them from the same page.

Comment: Thanks, however, these objects do not exist under custom objects nor do they show up in the drop-down when I try to add a new tab.

Comment: They may possibly be custom settings and not custom objects.
Try to find them under custom settings in setup.

Comment: That was it!  They live under Custom Settings.  Thanks so much @stefan-stojanovic.